# Please explain why this code prints 02002 and not 00022

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I don't understand why this code prints 02002 instead of 00022. From what i know, the order of constructor is: first base class, then member objects(in order of initialization list) then constructor of actual class. What do i get wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0)
        : m_i(n)
    {
        std::cout << m_i;
        ++m_i;
    }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 5) : m_a(new A[2]), m_x(++m_i) { std::cout << m_i; }

    ~B() { delete[] m_a; }

private:
    A m_x;
    A* m_a;
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The order of initialisation is not based on the order in the initialiser list.   The `m_i` in each of the `new A[2]` is distinct from each other and from the `m_i` of the `A` that is the base.

Answer (score 2):

Initialization order of member variables is always the declaration order, not the constructor initialization list order.

That means `B::m_x` will be initialized first, since it's declared first in the class.

See e.g. [this initialization order reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order) for details.